# WPF DataGrid DatePicker blackout dates on selected date

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datepicker

I have a DatePicker inside a Datagrid and I blackout all the dates before todays date

```
DatePicker datePicker = sender as DatePicker;
datePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
```

However, yesterday I have set a date of a picker to be 08/07/2014, so when I tried to open it up today which fired the above event, I get a exception as I believe the 8th cant be selected but of course, I have it already selected.

Is there a property or something I could use to stop this error from happening?

XAML

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <DatePicker CalendarOpened="DatePicker_CalendarOpened"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectedDate="{Binding From, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Thanks